# How to fetch1 million documents from elastic server.

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to export the data to a excel sheet. When i try to export this huge amount of data , the Elastic search server is not responding. Is there any work around to fetch this huge amount of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the value of `"size"` field in Elasticsearch search request to a very large value is not recommended. Use [`scan` and `scroll` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html) when you want to fetch such a huge number of documents.